# How to bulk check whether files have the same content

Tags: ruby, file

I would like to use Ruby to check if each of several thousand pairs of files contain identical information. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: use a checksum like shasum - if the shasums are the same, the contents are very likely to be the same.

Comment: Are you asking if the files contents are identical?

Comment: Yeah, I just need to know if each pair (pppp.txt and ff_pppp.txt) is identical. I'm not checking for overall uniqueness... there is a chance that pppp.txt is identical to nnnn.txt, but if so, it's irrelevant, because I only need to know if the pairs are a match.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.compare_file('file1','file2')
```

returns `true` if and only if files `file1` and `file2` are identical.